# How to use Spotlight Xamarin.Android Library in Xamarin.Forms Pages

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I wanted to install a library to Spotlight the `First Page` for the first time when users opens the app. For that I found this amazing library called [AndroidSpotlight](https://dev.azure.com/d3bugg3r/_git/AndroidSpotlight), but the problem is that I can't install that in `Xamarin.Forms` project as it's only for `Xamarin.Android`.

When I try to install it for `Xamarin.Forms` project, it gives me this error.

`Package Android.Spotlight 2019.11.14.1 is not compatible with netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1). Package Android.Spotlight 2019.11.14.1 supports: monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)`

But the first page is in `Xamarin.Forms`, so how could I use this library their?

`Views/IntroPage.xml` (I want to highlight the `ImageButton`)

```xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Mobile.App.Views.IntroPage"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Mobile.App.Control"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                        <ImageButton x:Name="SettingsButton"
                                     Source="drawable/icon.png"
                                     WidthRequest="20"
                                     HeightRequest="20"
                                     HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                     VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                     Command="{Binding SettingsButtonCommand}">
                        </ImageButton>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                         VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                // Code
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**UPDATE**

@Jason recommended to use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/).

It is working fine, but now their is a problem with [Spotlight Code](https://dev.azure.com/d3bugg3r/_git/AndroidSpotlight). In `Control\SpotLightService.cs`, the `Target()` required a Parameter called `view`. When I use the `Xamarin.Forms.View view`, it says `Cannot convert form 'Xamarin.Forms.ImageButton' to 'Android.Views.View'`.

But when I use `Android.View`, in `Views/IntroPage.xml.cs` I can't access `SettingsButton`, which I want to Spotlight.

`Views/IntroPage.xml.cs`

```
public partial class IntroPage : ContentPage
{
    public IntroPage()
    {
        DependencyService.Get<ISpotLight>().ShowIntro(SettingsButton, "settings");
    
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

`Services\ISpotLight.cs`

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Mobile.App.Services
{
    public interface ISpotLight
    {
        void ShowIntro(View view, string usageId);
    }
}
```

`Control\SpotLightService.cs`

using code from [AndroidSpotlight](https://dev.azure.com/d3bugg3r/_git/AndroidSpotlight?anchor=usage)

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(SpotLightService))]
namespace Mobile.App.Droid.Control
{
    public class SpotLightService : ISpotLight
    {
        private bool isRevealEnabled = true;
        private SpotlightView spotLight;

        public void ShowIntro(Xamarin.Forms.View view, string usageId)
        {
            spotLight = new SpotlightView.Builder((Activity)Application.Context)
                .IntroAnimationDuration(400)
                .EnableRevealAnimation(isRevealEnabled)
                .PerformClick(true)
                .FadeinTextDuration(400)
                .HeadingTvColor(Color.ParseColor("#eb273f"))
                .HeadingTvSize(32)
                .HeadingTvText("Love")
                .SubHeadingTvColor(Color.ParseColor("#ffffff"))
                .SubHeadingTvSize(16)
                .SubHeadingTvText("Like the picture?\nLet others know.")
                .MaskColor(Color.ParseColor("#dc000000"))
                .Target(view)
                .LineAnimDuration(400)
                .LineAndArcColor(Color.ParseColor("#eb273f"))
                .DismissOnTouch(true)
                .DismissOnBackPress(true)
                .EnableDismissAfterShown(true)
                .UsageId(usageId)
                .ShowTargetArc(true)
                .Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use DependencyService to access platform specific libraries from the core Forms project

Comment: thanks, i found this article https://alexdunn.org/2017/02/21/xamarin-tips-calling-platform-specific-code-from-a-portable-class-library-xamarin-forms-dependencyservice/ .. is this what you are referring to?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/

Comment: BTW, when you look at the doc @Jason mentions, don't make the mistake I did. I clicked on "Registration and Resolution", because I didn't realize Introduction was a separate page; I thought it was just that paragraph. I clicked straight into low-level details! Be sure to click ["Introduction"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) first. (can also get there from navigation hierarchy at left side of page).

Comment: thanks, I used the DependencyService, but their is a small problem using it.. I updated the code above, kindly have a look.. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Convert** `Xamarin.Forms.View`  to `Android.Views.View` , you can try the following code .

  ```
   public View ConvertFormsToNative(Xamarin.Forms.View view)
   {
         var vRenderer = Platform.CreateRendererWithContext(view, MainActivity.Instance);
         var Androidview = vRenderer.View;
         vRenderer.Tracker.UpdateLayout();

         var size = view.Bounds;
         var layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams((int)size.Width, (int)size.Height);
         Androidview.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
         view.Layout(size);
         Androidview.Layout(0, 0, (int)view.WidthRequest, (int)view.HeightRequest);
         Androidview.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Red);
         return Androidview;
    }
  ```

  and the `target` should be set as `.Target(ConvertFormsToNative(view))`
- **Change** `new SpotlightView.Builder((Activity)Application.Context)` to `new SpotlightView.Builder(MainActivity.Instance)` .

  `Instance` is a field defined in `MainActivity` .

  ```
     public static MainActivity Instance;
     protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
         base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

         Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
         global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

         Instance = this;
  ```
- **Move** the call of `Dependency service` from constructor to `LayoutChanged` event.

  ```
     public Page1()
     {

         InitializeComponent();

         this.LayoutChanged += Page1_LayoutChanged;

     }

     bool isShown = false;
     private void Page1_LayoutChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         if (!isShown)
         {
             DependencyService.Get<ISpotLight>().ShowIntro(SettingsButton, "settings");
             isShown = true;
         }
     }
  ```

Comment: You are the best... thanks.. just a small thing, I've basically this 3 buttons (1st on top-left, 2nd on top-right, 3rd on bottom-center).. I want that this white animation line to start from where the component is.. now, all (3 of them) starts from the top-left.. why?

Comment: like this https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wooplr/Spotlight/master/art/intro.gif?token=AA5ZAHdvAspW6Zj8YyyKamkV7jWXFtMHks5XaQovwA%3D%3D

Comment: Could you show the running image to elaborate it ?

Comment: I added a picture above, kindly have a look

Comment: Try to change `Androidview.Layout(0, 0, (int)view.WidthRequest, (int)view.HeightRequest);` to `Androidview.Layout((int)size.X, (int)size.Y, (int)view.WidthRequest, (int)view.HeightRequest);` .

Comment: a position just change a bit, but still 3 of them are on the top.