# SpotLight should Start Automatically in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

[@ColeX - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8187800/colex-msft) helped in the [implementation of SpotLight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68737292/14515147) in Xamarin Project.

1. Now, I want that when for the first time the app opens up, this spotlight should start
   automatically (android page).
2. And when it went off, the forms page should appear. I mean, how can I detect if all (3) spotlights are disappeared? so then I can navigate to the forms page, which will have the actual UI I want to show.

**Custom renderer for Page.**

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Page1), typeof(MainPageRenderer))]
namespace CustomRenderer.Droid
{
    class MainPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        private Android.Views.View view;
        private Android.Widget.Button button1;
        private Android.Widget.Button button2;
        private Android.Widget.Button button3;
        public MainPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
            {
                return;
            }


            view = MainActivity.Instance.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MyPage, this, false);
            AddView(view);


            view.Click += View_Click;

            button1 = view.FindViewById<Android.Widget.Button>(Resource.Id.firstButton);
            button2 = view.FindViewById<Android.Widget.Button>(Resource.Id.secondButton);
            button3 = view.FindViewById<Android.Widget.Button>(Resource.Id.thirdButton);

            
        }

        bool isShown_FirstButton_SpotLight = false;
        bool isShown_SecondButton_SpotLight = false;
        bool isShown_ThirdButton_SpotLight = false;
        private void View_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!isShown_FirstButton_SpotLight)
            {
                show(button1 ,"First Button" ,"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit", "FirstButton");
                isShown_FirstButton_SpotLight = true;
                return;
            }
            if (!isShown_SecondButton_SpotLight)
            {
                show(button2,"Second Button", "Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore eta", "SecondButton");
                isShown_SecondButton_SpotLight = true;
                return;
            }
            if (!isShown_ThirdButton_SpotLight)
            {
                show(button3,"Third Button", "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation", "ThirdButton");
                isShown_ThirdButton_SpotLight = true;
                return;
            }
        }

        void show(Android.Views.View view, string title, string subTitle, string usageId)
        {
            new SpotlightView.Builder(MainActivity.Instance)
                .IntroAnimationDuration(400)
                .EnableRevealAnimation(true)
                .PerformClick(true)
                .FadeinTextDuration(400)
                .HeadingTvColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#eb273f"))
                .HeadingTvSize(32)
                .HeadingTvText(title)
                .SubHeadingTvColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#eb273f"))
                .SubHeadingTvSize(16)
                .SubHeadingTvText(subTitle)
                .MaskColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#dc000000"))
                .Target(view)
                .LineAnimDuration(400)
                .LineAndArcColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#eb273f"))
                .DismissOnTouch(true)
                .DismissOnBackPress(true)
                .EnableDismissAfterShown(true)
                .UsageId(usageId)
                .ShowTargetArc(true)
                .Show();
        }

        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
        {
            base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

            var msw = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(r - l, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);
            var msh = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(b - t, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);

            view.Measure(msw, msh);
            view.Layout(0, 0, r - l, b - t);
        }
    }
}
```

**Resources/layout/MyPage**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/firstButton"
        android:layout_width="50dp"    
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"    
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"       
        android:text="First"
        android:background="#00ff00"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/secondButton"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"     
        android:text="Second"
        android:background="#ff0000"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/thirdButton"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:text="Third"
        android:background="#0000ff"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to proactively call the start animation method, and then call one of the methods defined in the page after all animations.

for example :

define a `FinishAnim` method in your page.cs:

```
public partial class YourPage: ContentPage
{
    public YourPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
 
    public void FinishAnim(){
        //navigate to other form page
    }
}
```

then start the animation in your renderer:

```
 protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
        {
            return;
        }


        view = MainActivity.Instance.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MyPage, this, false);
        AddView(view);

        button1 = view.FindViewById<Android.Widget.Button>(Resource.Id.firstButton);
        button2 = view.FindViewById<Android.Widget.Button>(Resource.Id.secondButton);
        button3 = view.FindViewById<Android.Widget.Button>(Resource.Id.thirdButton);

        //start the three animations
        show(button1 ,"First Button" ,"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit", "FirstButton");
        show(button2,"Second Button", "Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore eta", "SecondButton");
        show(button3,"Third Button", "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation", "ThirdButton");
        //if you want play the animation one by one,you could set some delay time for them or check the SpotlightSequence.getInstance(this, null).AddSpotlight(...).AddSpotlight(...)....StartSequence();method.
         
        //after animations
        YourPage page = (YourPage)Element;
        page.FinishAnim();
        
    }
```